# Regarding the issue with SSL in Http appender of log4j

Tags: ssl, log4j

I am using the log4j HTTP Appender with SSL to send the logs towards the HTTP server. I am using the correct xml and its working in the local, but while using the same xml in my application. log4j is not even initiating the ssl calls. I tried to debug from the application side also but didn't find any thing. Can you please help me out to get it work. below I am sharing my XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Http name="Http" url="https://127.0.0.1:9098">
            <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %m%n"/>
            <SSL>
                <KeyStore   location="/tmp/keystore.jks" password="123345"/>
                <TrustStore location="/tmp/truststore.jks" password="123345"/>
            </SSL>
        </Http>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="httpLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Http"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Http"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

in IP section, I am using the IP of my server.

I tried to debug the ssl using `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` evn variable, but now seeing any ssl related calls in my logs.I was suspecting the ssl certificate is not correct but seems its correct and working in local , but from the application side log4j is not initiating any calls.

Comment: You need to bump the logging level of the status logger do `DEBUG` (`status="DEBUG"`) to check what is going on. The status logger logs on the standard error.